# Angular: how to hide DOM element based on the number of filtered elements in model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's a simple controller that contains a list of users:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('project', [])
     .controller('UsersController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
         $scope.users = [
           { text: 'User 1', done: true, extension: 123 },
           { text: 'Another user', done: false, extension: 456 }];
     }]);

     $scope.selectedUsers = function () {
         var results = [];
         for (i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
             if ($scope.users[i].done) {
                 results.push($scope.users[i]);
             }
         }
         return results;
     };
</script>
```

And a simple HTML that just shows a checkbox for each user, and a message to select something if no user is selected.

```
<div ng-app="project" ng-controller="UsersController">

    <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-model="user.done" id="selectUser{{$index}}" />

    <div ng-hide="selectedUsers().length">Select something</div>     
</div>
```

The code works, but it looks kind of ugly.

Is there a less procedural way of getting to the same result?

Comment: Not only is it "ugly" :) - but it is very inefficient - you are essentially looping over the entire array on every digest

Comment: @newdev I had a sneaking suspicion that this would get called over and over. BUT. Doesn't a filter do basically the same? Is it smart enough to get triggered only on relevant changes in the model?

Comment: It would run every time and would be just as inefficient (although, cleaner). I added another approach you could take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply filter down the set of users based on the `done` property and check the length of it.

```
<div ng-hide="(users | filter:{done:true}).length">Select something</div>
```

```js
angular.module('project', [])
.controller('UsersController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
    { text: 'User 1', done: true, extension: 123 },
    { text: 'Another user', done: false, extension: 456 }];
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="project" ng-controller="UsersController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="user in users" ng-model="user.done" id="selectUser{{$index}}" />
  <div ng-hide="(users | filter:{done:true}).length">Select something</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it implemented is rather inefficient as the `selectedUsers` function, which iterates over all users, runs on every digest. It might be acceptable if you a small number of users.

For completeness sake, however, another approach would be to calculate the number of `user.done === true` and keep track of the count (rather than re-count):

```
$scope.users = [
   { text: 'User 1', done: true, extension: 123 },
   { text: 'Another user', done: false, extension: 456 }];

$scope.selection = {count: 0};
for (var i=0; i<$scope.users.length; i++){
   if ($scope.users[i].done) $scope.selection.count++;
}
```

And amend `selection.count` on each `ng-change` of selection:

```
<div ng-app="project" ng-controller="UsersController">

    <input type="checkbox" ng-repeat="user in users" 
           ng-model="user.done"
           ng-change="selection.count = selection.count + user.done * 2 - 1">

    <div ng-hide="selection.count">Select something</div>     
</div>
```

(Note, that it had I had to use an object `selection` that holds that property `count`; just using `$scope.selectionCount` would not have worked due to how prototypical inheritance works and the fact that `ng-repeat` creates a child scope)